# SQL Server - Hanging Process - SPID Query

Tags: sql-server, spid

How do I find what is the associated query that is being executed if I have the SPID. Trying to figure out what query is being associated since the process seems to be hung.

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

what version of sql server? for 2000 and up you can do

```
dbcc inputbuffer (spid)
```

That will give the first 255 characters

replace spid with the numerical number for spid

for 2005 and up, change @@SPID to the spid you are looking for

```
select dest.*
from  sys.dm_exec_requests as der
             cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (der.sql_handle) as dest
where session_id = @@spid
```

Answer (score 20):

```
--Find Current SQL Statements that are Running
SELECT   SPID           = er.session_id
        ,STATUS         = ses.STATUS
        ,[Login]        = ses.login_name
        ,Host           = ses.host_name
        ,BlkBy          = er.blocking_session_id
        ,DBName         = DB_Name(er.database_id)
        ,CommandType    = er.command
        ,ObjectName     = OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid)
        ,CPUTime        = er.cpu_time
        ,StartTime      = er.start_time
        ,TimeElapsed    = CAST(GETDATE() - er.start_time AS TIME)
        ,SQLStatement   = st.text
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests er
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) st
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ses
        ON ses.session_id = er.session_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections con
        ON con.session_id = ses.session_id
WHERE   st.text IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN statement_end_offset = -1
        THEN text
        ELSE SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2,(statement_end_offset- statement_start_offset)/2)
    END, *
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
WHERE session_id = <whatever>
```

You might want to download the "[Who is Active?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2010/10/21/who-is-active-v10-00-dmv-monitoring-made-easy.aspx)" procedure that pulls together a lot more information than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at it in the activity monitor you should be able to find the SQL associated with the SPID by right clicking and selecting "details".

Here are a few links to get you started:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298475
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188272.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx

You can also kill it from there as a last resort.